# Does creating YouTube tutorials on how to solve questions from textbooks infringe copyright?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

When the answer to a problem is not provided by the textbook (or even in the case that it is), would creating a YouTube or text-based tutorial on how to solve it infringe the copyright of the textbook writer, or be fair use?

Comment: "Is this fair use?" Do it, get sued, and see if the defense is held up. That's the only way to be sure.

Comment: I'm looking for the best guess of someone who has the experience in this that I do not. Do cases like this usually go a certain way? Does this count as a derivative work?

Comment: Your fair use would be on educational purpose grounds; it wouldn't matter the way in which you're claimed to breach copyright, since your defence is that you have an exception anyway.